# Check python version running a given script

Tags: python, terminal, version

Imagine I have installed two versions of python and I am running a `.py` file. I would like to know which of the two versions is running the script and eventually be able to change it.
The problem is that I do not know where to start from in order to get the information  even though it shouldn't be that taugh.

Could you please give me a little hint about it?

Comment: `import sys` followed by `print(sys.version)`

Comment: Do you want to do this from within the program? If you mean that you have a bunch of versions of Python installed and it's getting messy, the best solution is to use virtual environments, or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

there's a few different ways to do this from within a script, some good info here: [link](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-sys-platform-version-info/)

simplest is probably one of these

```
import sys
import platform
sys.version
sys.version_info
platform.python_version()
```